# Opposite of MySQL FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, sql, database, set

### How can I do the equivalent of:

```
!FIND_IN_SET('needle', haystack)
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) returns the index of the match if it is found, and returns 0 if it is not found. Since 0 is FALSE you can use `NOT FIND_IN_SET('needle', haystack)`

Comment: I agree with you but even his solution with ! instead of not does the trick. So I don't understand what's his problem :)

Comment: A note to anyone who may come across this question/solution, the use of `NOT FIND_IN_SET(...)` will only work correctly if your needle and haystack don't contain `NULL` values.  It's a case where logically reading the query it sounds correct, but following the return values will find it doesn't work since the function returns `NULL` if either param values contain a `NULL` value.

The proper way would be `FIND_IN_SET(...) IS NULL` to check for `NULL` BUT if your haystack could contain both `NULL` and and empty string `''`; then just do `NOT FIND_IN_SET(needle, IFNULL(haystack, '')`.

Answer (score 8):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

`FIND_IN_SET('needle', haystack) = 0` should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT id FROM table where !FIND_IN_SET(needle,haystack).......
```

**Its working for me...**

Answer (score 4):

It seems like it doesn't work if the field is NULL and therefore doesn't contain the value.

A workaround:

```
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(needle,haystack))
```

Hope it'll help!

Answer (score 1):

Equals to 0 doesn't work, you have to use null.

SELECT id FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(needle,haystack) IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

```
  .andWhere('(NOT FIND_IN_SET(:userID, notification.deletedBy) OR notification.deletedBy IS NULL)',{userID:userId})
```